# Blank pages in pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My code for pagination in woocomerce is the following:

```
        global $paged;
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'hide_empty'     => 1,
            'depth'          => 1,
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'orderby'        => 'name',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'update_post_term_cache' => false,
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
            'paged' => $paged
        );
                    
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        echo '<div class="woocomerce-paginador">';
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'   => max( 1, $loop->get( 'paged' ) ),
            'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
        ) );
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

I can not figured why but some pages are blank.

For example page one is blank, but page two has products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i figured out what was the problem.
I have products with no price, and pagination was trying to show no price products but instead it showed blank pages, because of condition i have in my code to only show priced products.

I solved the problem with a meta query.

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => '_price',
    'value' => 0,
    'compare' => '>',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
  )
),
```